# Send data to port in Elm as initial command

Tags: javascript, elm, ports

I have an outgoing port defined as follows:

```
port errors : List String -> Cmd msg
```

Then I define my program this way:

```
init : Flags -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags =
  ( initialModel flags, errors [ "an error" ] )

main : Program Flags Model Msg
main =
  Html.programWithFlags
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
```

It compiles and runs, but on the javascript side, **I don't see this first message**. Of course, if I interact further with the application I see that specific port sending data, so I'm sure it is working properly.

Comment: Just a doubt: it might be that there's a *racing condition* between Elm and JS? Because I'm using the MutationObserver to before accessing the ports (and then subscribing).

Comment: I wrote a [minimal example](https://ellie-app.com/HGvSwNr6G7a1/0) to try and replicate it but it is working correctly, so yea, perhaps there is something else you are doing in js that is interfering.

Comment: Actually, you are right and I'm surprised that your example is working: as far as I knew the ports weren't immediately available after calling `Elm.Main.fullscreen` (I'm using `embed` though, but should be the same).

Comment: [This example](https://ellie-app.com/HGvSwNr6G7a1/1) using 'embed' also works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that this is a race condition with your JS & Elm app. Make sure to load your JS app in your index.html before initializing your Elm app.

```html
<body>
<pre id="elm"></pre>
<script src="elm.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bundle.js" type="module"></script>
<script>
    let app = Elm.Main.init({node: document.getElementById("elm")});
</script>
</body>
```